# input type file tag loaded from ajax result not working in mobile

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have the input type file tag loaded from result of ajax, When I click the choose button, the choose file dialog opens and I can choose a file, but the Problem is the PHP **$_FILES['pic']['error']** has value **4** which file was not uploaded. It works fine when  tag loaded on window load, but not in ajax.

Here is the HTML code I am using
**Html code**

**Jquery code**:
`$('#upload_pic').on('change', function()
{
    $('#form_pic').submit();
});`

Comment: Here is the HTML code used
<form id="form_pic" action="savePic.php" method="POST" target="mobile_frame_target">
 <ifrmae id="mobile_frame_target"></iframe>
 <input type="file" name="pic" id="upload_pic"/>
</form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change it and submit the form in your iframe, in this case you don't need AJAX to send the uploaded picture to PHP:

```
 <iframe id="mobile_frame_target">
    <form id="form_pic" action="savePic.php" method="POST" target="mobile_frame_target" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type="file" name="pic" id="upload_pic"/> 
    </form> 

    //Include JQuery library
    <script>
        $('#upload_pic').on('change', function()
        {
            $('#form_pic').submit();
        });
    </script>
 </iframe>
```